# Can't find sqlite3 when compling my project

Tags: c, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I'm working on a small project in c that works with DB's using sqlite3. I'm using Eclipse CDT.
Here's a relevant code snippet:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: database name not specified!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sqlite3* db;
    sqlite3_open("movies.db", db);

    return 0;
}
```

I also have my file "sqlite3.so" in the project directory.
When I try to compile it, I get "cannot find -lsqlite3" error.

I've added the file in the linker (in the project properties) but I still get this error.
What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: unrelated, but important: **turn on your compiler warnings** and **pay attention** to them. `sqlite3_open("movies.db", db);` isn't gonna do anything good.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant it's just a concept for making the question more in detail. I would like first for my program to compile!

Comment: Try passing `-L/home/test` before -lsqlite3, Lets say `/home/test` is where your sqlite3.so is

Comment: If you want your `sqlite3.so` to be automatically loaded from your project's directory, you sould specify it as `./sqlite3.so` instead of `-lsqlite3`

Comment: @Miline I tried that and it still doesn't find it.

Comment: @GreenScape How this can be done via Eclipse?

Comment: @DanielY, never used eclipse myself, so my only advice can be: look in the Settings -> Linked options, and the somewere out there must be an option to add library from file.

Answer (score 5):

I am quite sure this is working for you now or you have totally forgotten about this. In any case, since there is no accepted answer, I am writing one.

When you install `sqlite3`, headers and libraries necessary for development are not installed. You have to get them installed separately from the package `libsqlite3-dev`. So the below command should do the trick.

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Just remember that this is the case for most of the third party softwares on Linux in general and Ubuntu in perticular. So, if you need ssl library you install it from `libssl-dev` package.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you got your sqlite3.so from. But here is what I did(not inside Eclipse) and it worked.

1. Download and uncompress sources of sqlite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-autoconf-3080803.tar.gz
2. Configure

   ```
   CFLAGS="-Os" ./configure --prefix=/mnt/store/sqlite-autoconf-3080803/build/
   ```
3. make

   ```
   make install
   ```
4. Get your code and do some changes `sqlite3_open("movies.db", &db);` and add `#include <stdio.h>`
5. compile your code

   ```
   gcc test.c -I/mnt/store/sqlite-autoconf-3080803/build/include -L/mnt/store/sqlite-autoconf-3080803/build/lib/ -lsqlite3
   ```

Comment: I use Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Ohh. I am sorry then. Though this can help someone else.

Comment: Note that if you are using windows, you shouldn't have libsqlite3.so, that's for linux. You'd need sqlite3.lib/sqlite3.dll or something similar.

Comment: this worked for me! ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Rename your local file to *libsqlite3.so*, or even better, create a link *libsqlite3.so -> sqlite3.so*. And, as suggested above, you have to add -L/project/dir to the command line.

Comment: Done, and still "cannot find -llibsqlite3"

Comment: Can you check the permissions of library?

Comment: @Miline how can I do that?

Comment: OK I checked it, I have full access to the library

Comment: Can you try compiling outside eclipse?